Modify Websocket request header before sending in android webview
I have an Android WebView where WebSocket requests are initiated. I need to modify the headers of these WebSocket requests before they are sent inside the WebView. I've tried using shouldInterceptRequest in my custom WebViewClient, but it only intercepts HTTP requests, not WebSocket requests.
I've logged the URL of WebSocket requests using request.getUrl().toString(), but none are intercepted. Is there a way to intercept and modify WebSocket request headers in Android WebView? If not, are there alternative frameworks or methods to achieve this?
In Electron JS, I successfully modified headers for WebSocket requests using session.defaultSession.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders. However, I need a similar solution tailored for Android.
class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView webView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        webView = findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
        webView.loadUrl("https://panel.autotcrypto.com");
    }

    private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
            String url = request.getUrl().toString();
            if (url.contains("ws")) {
                // Code attempts to modify headers (not effective for WebSocket)
            }
            return super.shouldInterceptRequest(view, request);
        }
    }
}

